# How does this code to forbid inheritance work?

Tags: c++, inheritance, hierarchy, access-modifiers

I found some rather strange code:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual bool IsDerived() const { return false; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    bool IsDerived() const { return true; }
};

Derived* CastToDerived( Base* base )
{
    // private and protected inheritance from Derived is prohibited
    Derived* derived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(base);
    if( derived == 0 ) {
       assert( !base->IsDerived() );
    }
    return derived;
}
```

I don't get the passage about private and protected inheritance.

Suppose, I inherit from `Derived` with `protected` modifier:

```
class FurtherDerived : protected Derived {
};
```

What happens? How will that `assert` get triggered?

Comment: Please explain " I inherit from Derived with protected modifier"
You are saying derive a new derived class from 'derived' class or protected inheritance of 'base' class  ?

Comment: Where did you find this code? It doesn't make any sense. If `Derived` is not publicly inheriting from `Base` the only thing that can be passed to `CastToDerived()` is a `Base` pointer, because there wouldn't be any way to convert a `Derived` pointer to a `Base` pointer. So the assertion can never be triggered.

Comment: @Praetorian there are ways to get Base pointer from Derived even when Base is a private ancestor. For example, by adding `Base* Derived::getBase() { return this; }`

Comment: @Eugene Homyakov Ok, good example, I wasn't think of having an explicit conversion function.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Protected` or `Private` Inheritance, You cannot do:

```
Base *ptr = new Derived();
```

neither can you do,

```
Derived *ptr1 = new Derived();
Base *ptr = ptr1;
```

This is because, `Base` is an inaccessible base of `Derived`

<strike>Since you cannot have a `Base` class pointer pointing to `Derived` class object, that check looks redundant.</strike>

---

**EDIT:**
Even if you cannot directly assign an `Derived` class object to an `Base` class pointer, It can happen so in some other ways like: If a function of `Derived` class returns a `Base` class pointer.

In short, A `Base` class pointer may point to a `Derived` class object even if derivation is `protected` or `private`.

Given the above,

As per C++ standard:
**5.2.7.8:**

> The run-time check logically executes as follows:
>   —  If, in the most derived object pointed (referred) to by v, v points (refers) to a public base class sub- object of a T object, and if only one object of type T is derived from the sub-object pointed (referred) to by v, the result is a pointer (an lvalue referring) to that T object.
>   — ***Otherwise, if v points (refers) to a public base class sub-object of the most derived object, and the type of the most derived object has a base class, of type T, that is unambiguous and `public`, the result is a pointer (an lvalue referring) to the T sub-object of the most derived object***.
>   —  Otherwise, the run-time check fails.

Note that the standard specifically imposes the requirement of the derivation to be, **Public.**
Thus `dynamic_cast` will detect the treat the cast as an improper cast if derivation is `protected` or `private` and return a `NULL`(since you are using a pointer) and the `assert` will be called.

**So Yes, the code is very much valid. And it indeed does what the comment says**

---

This **[sample](http://www.ideone.com/q0PAh)**, demonstrates that it works as per the comments:

```
#include<iostream>
class Base 
{
    public:
        virtual bool IsDerived() const { return false; }
};

class Derived : protected Base 
{
    public:
        bool IsDerived() const { return true; }
        Base* getBase() { return this; }
};

Derived* CastToDerived( Base* base )
{
     // private and protected inheritance from Derived is prohibited
     Derived* derived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(base);
     if( derived == 0 ) 
     {
         std::cout<< "!base->IsDerived()";
     }
     return derived;
}


int main()
{
    Derived *ptr3 = new Derived();
    Base *ptr = ptr3->getBase();
    Derived *ptr2 = CastToDerived(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You misread the question. `Derived` has public inheritance from `Base` . It is a given. The question is with regard to some class `NonPublicDerived` that has private or protected inheritance from class `Derived`.

Comment: @David Hammen: I don't understand which `NonPublicDerived` class you are referring to here.

Comment: The class to which I am referring is some unspecified class that derives from class `Derived`. Here is the question the OP asked us to answer: "*Suppose, I inherit from `Derived` with protected modifier. What happens?*". Nothing there about how class `Derived` is formed. How class `Derived` is formed is a given: public inheritance from class `Base`. The question is about some unspecified class that inherits from `Derived`, but does so with either `protected` or `private` inheritance.

Comment: @David Hammen: I am not sure I understand what you want to say, As i read the Q the OP clearly asks here, whether that `dynamic_cast` can do what the comment says it does i.e. assert if the derivation was private or protected. And the answer is Yes it does. And the reason is the standard specifically uses the word **public** while defining the `dynamic_cast` as the answer points out.

Comment: Did you try it as the OP asked? I did. See my answer. You are answering a question that the OP didn't ask. The OP never asked about `class Derived : protected Base`.

Comment: @David Hammen: Does the code example listed above in the answer not do what the comments in the code say? I give up. Too late now for me & too sleepy to try to understand what you mean to say.

Comment: "_You cannot do:_" of course you can, just not in every context!

Answer (score 0):

`IsDerived` is a virtual function defined in the base class, and the functions are resolved based on the *static* type of the object using which you invoke the function. That means, that's not a problem. It will work. (Or maybe, I missed something in your question).

Comment: -1: Invoking a member function that is declared virtual in some base class with a base class pointer will result in a call to the most derived implementation of that method. If C++ worked the way you claim it does a huge mountain of C++ programs that depend on C++ doing virtual dispatch would never work.

Comment: @David: You either misunderstood my post Or don't know how virtual dispatch happens. All I'm saying is this : http://ideone.com/HsTrg . Explain its output to me!

Answer (score 0):

`dynamic_cast` performs run-time check (5.2.7/8).

The runtime check will fail, if `Base` is inherited as protected or private by `Derived`.

The value of failed run-time check when casting to a pointer is a NULL pointer (5.2.7/9).

So, the code is a workaround for private and protected descendants: if you inherit `Derived` with `protected` or `private`, `dynamic_cast` will return NULL and the custom check will be performed.

Comment: Ok, but how can the caller of `CastToDerived` convert a `Derived` pointer to a `Base` pointer if inheritance is not public?

Comment: See my another comment in the original post :)

Comment: This question is not how `Derived` inherits from `Base`. That is a given. The question is "Suppose, I inherit from `Derived` with protected modifier. What happens?"

Comment: @David I've supposed it makes more sense that the comment doesn't mean what it says, than that one day `dynamic_cast` magically returned 0 when it shouldn't.

Comment: @Eugene: *Exactly*. My guess is that the author of this code was trying to solve a problem, guessed the wrong cause, and wrote a non-working solution to this wrong guess. He later solved the real problem but never deleted his mostly harmless junk. Typical cargo cult debugging stuff. I said "mostly harmless" because this is a bomb just waiting to go off. Someday someone will write some class `Foo : public Base` that also overrides `IsDerived()`. Applying `CastToDerived` on a `Foo` pointer will drop core.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't get the passage about private and protected inheritance.

The answer is simple. This comment like many, many other comments, is a comment that does not describe the code in any way, shape, or form.

Example:

```
class PrivateDerived : private Derived {
public:
   Base* cast_to_base () {
      return dynamic_cast<Base*>(this);
   }   
};  

void check_base (const char * id, Base* pbase) {
   if (pbase == 0) {
      std::cout << id << " conversion yields a null pointer.\n";
   }
   else {
      std::cout << id << "->IsDerived() = "
                << pbase->IsDerived() << "\n";
      Derived* pderived = CastToDerived (pbase);
      std::cout << "CastToDerived yields "
                << (pderived ? "non-null" : "null") << " pointer.\n";
      std::cout << "pderived->IsDerived() = "
                << pderived->IsDerived() << "\n\n";
   }
}

int main () {
   PrivateDerived private_derived;

   // Good old c-style cast can convert anything to anything.
   // Maybe a bit disfunctional, but it works in this case.
   check_base ("c_style_cast", (Base*)&private_derived);

   // The cast_to_base method can see the private inheritance,
   // and does so without invoking undefined behavior.
   check_base ("cast_method", private_derived.cast_to_base());

   return 0;
}
```

Tested with multiple versions of gcc and clang; none of them raised that `assert` statement.

**Addendum**
I suspect that what happened was that on some particular machine with some particular compiler, the code in question did somehow manage to do what the author thought it should do. I suspect that the author never tested this supposed check to see if it actually worked as advertised.

Comment: assertion fails if Derived has protected or private inheritance from Base. as in the question: "Suppose, I inherit from Derived with protected modifier."

Comment: @mkb: I tested the above code with multiple compilers. The assertion did not fail with any one of them. That said, I obviously do not have access to every C++ compilers out there. It may well fail with some. If the above does fail with one, I would be curious.

Comment: I said if **Derived** has protected or private inheritance, not **PrivateDerived**.

Comment: What is it with this question that so many of the answers are completely orthogonal to the question at hand? Here is what the OP asked: **Suppose, I inherit from `Derived` with protected modifier. What happens? How will that assert get triggered?** Not a word in that question regarding what happens if class `Derived` has non-public inheritance from `Base`.